# Module '" "' has no exported member 'NativeGeocoderReverseResult' in ionic 3 Geolocation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

**Module '" "' has no exported member 'NativeGeocoderReverseResult'.
      L13:  import { Geolocation }                       from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
      L14:  import { NativeGeocoder, NativeGeocoderOptions,NativeGeocoderReverseResult}** [Error In Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFkfe.png)

```
getUserLocation(){
        let options: NativeGeocoderOptions = {
            useLocale: true,
            maxResults: 5
        };
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(resp => {
            this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude, options)
            .then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult[]) => {
                this.userlocation = result[0].toString();
            }, error => {
            console.log(error)
            });
        }, error => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when use the code from ionic docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-geocoder

Then I found out that **NativeGeocoderReverseResult replaced with NativeGeocoderResult**:   https://github.com/sebastianbaar/cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder/releases

> v3.2.0
>   ...
>   ** BREAKING CHANGES **
>   replace NativeGeocoderForwardResult with NativeGeocoderResult
>   replace NativeGeocoderReverseResult with NativeGeocoderResult